# Android Sip cannot received call from another application

Tags: android, sip

I tried Sip Android example in [here](https://www.gitorious.org/0xdroid/development/source/a025796211f15c2796f8ea3208c066801aa250b6:samples/SipDemo)

The problem is:

When i use Sip Android call to another application (like Linphone app on iOS & Android). It's worked well.

But I use Linphone to call back to Android Sip. It didn't received the call.

I used two 2 android phone using Sip Android to call each other. It worked.

Anyone have ideas? Thanks

**UPDATED:**

I debug in log and it logged error like this:

> 02-03 13:30:49.206: W/AudioGroup(5927): device loop timeout
>
> 02-03 13:47:06.632: W/ActivityManager(736): getTasks: caller 10089
>   does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output

Comment: Dump the protocol log to see what's happening with session negotiation of the two peers in the call

Comment: It's look like BroadcastReceiver didn't received the call.

Comment: sample dump rtsp / sip session negotiation : http://snipplr.com/view/56509/youtube-rtsp-cli-request--audio-track-only/